# Why my directive isn't working with a ng-bind-html directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got the following directive

```
productApp.directive('notification', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : false,
        scope : {
            type: "=",
            message: "="
        },
        template: '<div class="alert {{type}} alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>{{message}}</div>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
            $timeout(function() {
                element.hide();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

In the view i got this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="notificationPoint">
        <!-- <notification type="alert.type" message="alert.msg"></notification>-->
    </div>
```

And inside the controller i'm doing this:

```
$scope.notificationPoint = '<notification type='alert-success' message='this is a test'></notification>'
```

So as you may realise, i wanted to make a "notification wrapper" that will contain all the notifications (childs) (using notification directive) when for example i add a row in the database, remove a product or whatever. So this wrapper will continously contain notifications appearing and dissapearing.

Happens that when i look into the source code when running it, nothing is inserted into the wrapper div, is not even passing to the directive code now when using the ng-bind-html directive.

Does anyone know if this is a bug? or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why are you even trying to use `ng-bind-html`? It's not for passing in directive templates

Comment: hey again charlie! :') what else i can do to achieve that? :( i would like to have a static parent wrapper containing all the notifications that im going to be sending from the controller to the view with dynamic data.

Comment: pass data text messages to directive, or events perhaps, but configure html in directive

Comment: happens that, if i add the <notification> in the view just like that... first off, i won't have any control of it, and it will appear whenever a refresh the page, but it won't appear anymore, even i call it from the controller, the directive object in the view itself gets "eliminated" after closing it. That's why i thought about adding a parent wrapper that is "reachable" from the controller and can hold all my notifications :/

Comment: well you need a lot more capability like a flag for `ng-show` logic to change message etc and decide what will control messages...events, service etc

Comment: study other directives source code

Comment: Yeah, i believe i'm going to do that, since with my current approach i won't get any further hahaha

Comment: glad you realize that...just a lot missing to make it work

Comment: OMG charlie, look what im going to post as an answer i found a godlike library for notifications.

Comment: yes... partly why i suggested you look into other directives

Answer (score 1):

As others said in the comment, you should pass message text to the directive. However, answer to your original question: `ng-bind-html` must be used with content trusted by `$sce`. For example:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($sce) {
  ...
  $scope.notificationPoint = $sce.trustAsHtml('<notification type='alert-success' message='this is a test'></notification>')
  ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up using Angular-Flash module for what i needed, check it out! IS AMAZING to send notifications to the view so eaasy and nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

i found this library for notifications, ITS INCREDIBLE how easy is to install, how easy is to use! just by calling from the controller

```
flash.success = 'Test!';
```

Then, inject the service in the controller.

You will send to the view a notification of success inside a wrapper (as i wanted to do)

The library is called angular-flash. Here's the github with the API doc

https://github.com/wmluke/angular-flash

Enjoy as much as i did!!! HAHA AMAZING I LOVE IT *-*